# Using Real-Time-Voice-Cloning and getting the error "failed to import any qt binding"

Tags: python, conda

I want to use this [GitHub](https://github.com/CorentinJ/Real-Time-Voice-Cloning) code for some purpose of mine. I'm on Mac (Sierra 10.12). So, I downloaded Anaconda on my Mac, and then opened up the terminal and typed

```
conda create -n robin python=3.7
```

and then typed `source activate robin`

I think that took me to my virtual environment. Then I downloaded the main github code, extracted it and then downloaded Pretrained models and extracted it in the same folder as the main github code.

Then I installed `pytorch` by the code given in its official page. And then typed `pip install -r requirements.txt` (by changing the directory to the Real-Time-Voice-Cloning folder).

I typed this code `pip install webrtcvad-wheels`. I thought that everything was done and therefore, I typed `python demo_toolbox.py` but got an error like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENag6.png)

I tried installing `pip3 install PyQt5`and even `conda install pyqt` and they were get installed. After that, I typed `python demo_toolbox.py` but the same error appeared again. How to get that GUI toolbox?

I'm a beginner in programming so it will be more helpful if you can provide step by step processing.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  What does "...and they were get installed." mean? The GitHub repo says that Python 3.6 or 3.7 is required to run the package. Are you using one of those two versions of Python?

Comment: @DaveL17 Yes, I'm using Python 3.7.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using linux. Try : sudo apt-install qt5 or pyqt5